# Firebird and Entity Framework case sensitve table/column names

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, firebird

When working with Firebird I can query a table and its columns without worrying about case. If I want case sensitivity I can put the table/column name in quotes.

The Firebird Entity Framework connector automatically puts quotes around names when generating queries, and as a result it forces case sensitivity on me.

This means I have a bunch of [Table("SOMETABLE")] and [Column("DESCRIPTION")] all over the place because my existing table names are in all-caps.

How can I tell the EF connector for Firebird to not be case sensitive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. The names will be always quoted. You have to provide real names, the ORM doesn't rely on fallback logic in engine when using different casing.

OTOH you can create tables and columns using quoted identifiers and the casing will be then preserved.