# Entity Framework and Firebird DB Dialect 1 - not generating compatible sql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, firebird, firebird2.5

I am trying to setup a project with EF on top of a firebird DB but it is generating extra quotes that the Firebird db is rejecting.

The db already exists and there is a matching record for this query there.
Error is
FbException: Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 2, column 4
.

However if I remove the quotes it generates in the sql the query runs.

Example

```
using (var context = new ContextManager())
{
     var accounts = context.Accounts.Where(x => x.OBJID == 1).ToList();
}
```

generates sql

```
SELECT 
"A"."OBJID" AS "OBJID"
FROM "ACCOUNT" AS "A"
```

Config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" type="FirebirdSql.Data.EntityFramework6.FbProviderServices, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" publicKeyToken="3750abcc3150b00c" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

<system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
            <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data></configuration>
```

Context class

```
public class ContextManager : DbContext
    {
        public ContextManager() : base(new FbConnection("database=xxxx.fdb;DataSource=localhost;user=xxx;password=xxxxx"),true)
        {

        }

        public ContextManager(string connString) : base(new FbConnection(connString), true)
        {
            //this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }
```

Account Model

```
[Table("ACCOUNT")]
    public class Account
        {
            [Key]
            public int OBJID { get; set; }
        }
```

Update - checked and saw dialect 1 was set so I updated the query string to denote it, the query did not change but the error did
FbException: Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 2, column 4
.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what is the problem? The SQL you show is valid SQL for Firebird (unless you use a dialect 1 database, which you shouldn't be using as dialect 1 was deprecated 18 years ago). The only thing I see is that the `where` clause is missing. The SQL supported by Firebird is pretty close to the syntax defined in the ISO SQL standard, so you will need to be more specific than just saying _"generating 'normal' sql instead of Firebird sql"_. If you get an error, then please show that error, or otherwise explicitly specify what is wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question to add information like that.

Comment: I checked and it is indeed dialect 1

Comment: Ah, that is a different problem than what I wrote my answer for. I'm not sure if there is a way to get it to generate SQL without double quotes. In dialect 1, double quotes delimit strings, instead of quoted object names. Is this an 'old' database for an application that depends on the legacy behavior of dialect 1? If it is a new application, it might be better to start from scratch with dialect 3, if it is an existing database, then you'll need to recreate the database as dialect 3 and pump the data (and of course test if your application isn't relying on the legacy behavior of dialect 1).

Comment: This company has existed for over 20 years and I believe the original owner was somehow involved with firebird development, they have thousands of instances of it here. I cannot say why things are the way they are, I just have to deal with it.

Comment: "for over 20 years " - so they started when Dialect 1 was primary or even only language and Dialect 3 was new and maybe was considered shaky. They just did not invested into rewriting the working application when dialect 3 was just out, and later when their app grew larger and larger they has still less incentive to do so. I remember there were subtle problems in FB3 with Dialect 1, guess this app is anchored in FB2 forever. /// On unrelated note, this is SO FB question #2600, such a "round number" :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your database is dialect 1, and Entity Framework is quoting the object names. Unfortunately quoted object names are not supported in dialect 1, and are instead interpreted as strings. This leads to the token unknown errors, as the parser isn't expecting strings, but object names.

It has been a while since I did anything with entity framework (I normally program in Java), and I'm not sure if there is an option to disable quoting.

According to this ticket in the Firebird bug tracker, the Firebird Entity Framework support does not and will not support dialect 1: [DNET-580](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-580).

So unless you upgrade your database to dialect 3, it looks like you will not be able to use Entity Framework. Be aware that upgrading from dialect 1 to dialect 3 may not be simple, especially not if your application(s) rely on dialect 1 specific syntax (eg double quotes for strings) or behaviour (floating point division for integers).

### Workaround

A potential workaround is to explicitly specify your connection dialect as dialect 3 (connection property `Dialect=3` for the Firebird ADO.net provider). This will allow you to query the database using dialect 3 syntax. Be aware there might be some differences in behavior, as dialect 3 has a number of different rules.

I'm a bit surprised though, because I tested a number of recent versions of the Firebird ADO.net provider and it defaults to dialect 3 unless explicitly set to 1, so this shouldn't be an issue at all.

## Similar problems with dialect 3

This part of the answer assumes a dialect 3 database where the table is actually called `ACCOUNTS`, and not `Accounts`. This would not result in a token unknown, but in a table unknown error.

In this situation, the problem is that the default configuration derives names from objects, and it will quote names. Quoted names in dialect 3 are case sensitive (unquoted names are case insensitive but are stored (and compared) as uppercase).

What you can do is override the table name by annotating your object:

```
[Table("ACCOUNTS")]
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public int OBJID { get; set; }
}
```

Another option you could use is the fluent API, but I have never used it myself, so I'm not entirely sure where you need to specify this (I think in your `DbContext`).

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  //Changing Database table name to Metadata
  modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
      .ToTable("ACCOUNTS");
}
```

There might be other options to influence naming conventions.

See also [Entity Framework Code First - Changing a Table Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656617/entity-framework-code-first-changing-a-table-name)

Comment: There was a point it was adding the plural 's' when I didn't want to which I had to use the decorator to avoid but alas it was not the root of the issue.

Comment: That automatic pluralization can be removed by `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention>();` in `OnModelCreating`; maybe there is a similar configuration for quoting object names. But I haven't found one.

Comment: I'm giving you the answer credit because this indeed seems to be the case -> http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-580

Comment: @PaulSwetz Yes, I just found that one as well. I'll try to see if I can find anything else, but I'm not hopeful.

Comment: @PaulSwetz [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10812201/466862) suggests it is not possible to disable quoting.

Comment: @PaulSwetz It might be possible to workaround this by explicitly specifying dialect 3 as the connection dialect, but I don't have the time to verify that right now. You would still have to map the names to their uppercase equivalents.

Comment: well I've spun up an interceptor that can remove the quotes but this will probably turn into a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Even if it will be possible to "disable quoting" it will still be subject to Heisenbugs over every other difference between the Dialects. The library either does support D1 or not. Frankly, even if it would be possible to suppress quotes I would suggest against that very fragile and undetermenistic hack.

Comment: That said, the DNET-580 Reporter: Jar Jar Binks said he made EF fork that supports D1, maybe that fork can be still found and used instead of vanilla provider.